# How to make a cookie with PHP

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set cookies for uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750658/how-to-set-cookies-for-uuid)

Hello, I would like to know how to make a cookie in PHP. I have researched the topic for a couple of hours already, yet im a newbie to PHP and dont understand it that much. I have found this script, but dont know how to implant it into my website, can anyone help?

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);
```

Comment: first you start with butter and flour.....

Comment: http://www.tutorialcode.com/php/php-basics-php-beginner-tips/ maybe...

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to do with your cookie?  If you want to track information on the server from request-to-request, you probably want to use a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php), which automatically uses cookies.

Otherwise, go ahead and use [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for cookies that your application needs for other functionality.  Pay attention to this snippet from the PHP manual:

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be
>   sent along with the rest of the HTTP
>   headers. Like other headers, cookies
>   must be sent before any output from
>   your script (this is a protocol
>   restriction). This requires that you
>   place calls to this function prior to
>   any output, including  and
>    tags as well as any whitespace.

---

```
<?php setcookie("cookiename", uniqid()); ?>
```

Comment: i want the cookies to save the output of a uniqid() output. Can you show an example of a script which can do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

make sure you put it before anything is output to the page (like you do with headers)

so:

```
<?php

//fill in with the info you want
$name = 'theCookie';
$value = 'tasty';
$expire = null;
$path = '/';
$domain = null;

setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain);

...rest of code

?>
```

Comment: thanks, but can you please explain what the "name, value, expire, path, domain" are and what to put in place of them? Sorry, im new to this.

Comment: name is the name of cookie, value is the value of the cookie, expire is the time that it should expire in milliseconds, path is the path the cookie should stick to domain is the domain name. domain is by default the domain that the user is on

Comment: thanks for the clarification, but i have one more question. I am using uniqid() to generate a unique id on my website. How can i use this cookie script to save the output of the uniqid() for the visitor?

Comment: dont use cookies, they are not very obfuscated and the user can edit it easily, fo that i would suggest using `$_SESSION` vars

Comment: i have read about using sessions, but i believe that the session data is destroyed once the visitor leaves the page, am i correct? I want the uniqid() to be saved for prolonged periods of time, even when the visitor closes his browser or leaves the page.

Comment: it will be destroyed when the user closes the browser

Comment: so its not what I need. Is there an alternative? Like maybe saving it using the visitor's IP?

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer.

```
<?php
setcookie("TestCookie", "myValue", time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", ".example.com", 1);
?>
```

This creates a cookie called TestCookie with a value of "myValue", it will expire 1 hour from its creation.  The website/domain is example.com and the folder path you're in is /~rasmus/.

More information on setcookie here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: how can i change the value to match the output of uniqid()?

Comment: Use a variable: $result = uniqid()
Then place $result in place of "myValue"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example

```
<? setcookie("foobar", "Hello, world!", -1) ?>
```

This will create a cookie named "foobar" with the value of "Hello, world!", and will expire when the browser closes.

Also, make sure you set cookies before any HTML output otherwise it won't be created.

To check it's value, do on a following page.

```
<? echo $_COOKIE['foobar']; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i have two questions, 1. How can i change the expiration time? 2. By "making sure you set cookies before any HTML output otherwise it won't be created", do you mean that i shoudld put the cookie script before the <head> tags?

Comment: To change the expiration there are multiple ways to do it, but if you wanted it to last 24 hours, do time() + (60 * 60 *24). ---

Put the PHP code before the HTML tag if possible, but yes, definitely before the HEAD tag.