# How to set cookies for uuid

Tags: php, cookies, uuid

I have a website which generates a uuid every time the page is loaded/refreshed. I want to make it so that a certain value remains the same for a period of time using cookies. Does anyone know of a script which can help me?

Comment: erm, have you tried sessions ?

Comment: i cant use sessions. I want the uuid to remain the same for a long period of time for every new visitor (i.e a month), so sessions wont help.

Comment: If you aren't able to use sessions, why do cookies matter at all in this equation?

Comment: you people need to read more carefully. Im able to use sessions, BUT i cant use them since sessions end when the browser is closed.

Comment: Not necessarily. Sessions (usually) are maintained by cookies, so they can stay alive as long as cookies (assuming the server won't remove them).

Comment: you can always dp `$_SESSION['uuid'] = $x`, and then do `$_SESSION['uuid_expires'] = time() + 3600`, you just need to do a few check's and you can keep it server side

Comment: Indeed. You can set [`session.cookie_lifetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) and `session.gc_maxlifetime` to get long-lived sessions. Albeit the latter should be used with care (disk clogging from unused sessions).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are asking for a script, or what the problem here is. To set a cookie, just use:

```
if (empty($_COOKIE["uuid"])) {
    $uuid = uniqid();  // or use a real UUID
    setcookie("uuid", $uuid, time()+30*24*60*60, "/");
}
else {
    $uuid = $_COOKIE["uuid"];
}
```

Actually you should execute the setcookie once in a while and anyway to have the cookie lifetime refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie that's deleted when the browser session closes. That can be used as a signal for when the user is "revisiting" the site. Storing a uuid cookie on each page will then give you the last uuid from which you can do what you were requesting.

```
setcookie('firstvisit', 1);
setcookie('uuid', $uuid, time()+368400);
if(isset($_COOKIE['firstvisit']) && isset($_COOKIE['uuid'])) {
    // load uuid content
}
```

Comment: Every time you run setcookie() with $uuid it will replace the value of 'uuid' in the cookie.