# How to save uuid result with cookies

Tags: php, cookies, uuid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set cookies for uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750658/how-to-set-cookies-for-uuid)

I have a website with a uniqid() generator. There is a box with the uuid on my site which changes with each page visit. I want to set a cookie which saves the uuid output and loads it the next time a returning visitor vists my site. anyone know a cookie script for this?