# Help with cookie in php

Tags: php, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set cookies for uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750658/how-to-set-cookies-for-uuid)

Hello here's my site, http://xblgenerator.co.cc . It generates a random id everytime the page is refreshed. I have set a cookie so now the id stays the same for every new visitor until they clear their c ookie. My only problem is that the id also appears on the top left corner of my page (just refresh the page twice and you'll see it). Here's my cookie:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["uuid"]))
   echo $_COOKIE["uuid"] ;
else
   setcookie("uuid", "$rnd_id", time()+368400000);
?>
```

Can anyone tell me what to change so that the little id on the top doesn't appear?

Comment: Just remove the `echo` if you don't want anything printed. Also please apply curly braces. They are only syntactically optional, not advisably.

Comment: Looks like everyone gave the same answer in the same minute,, looks pritty obvious now does it?

Comment: lol xD i cant believe i didnt notice that, thanks!

Comment: You're incrementally having StackOverflow write your application for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751194/how-to-save-uuid-result-with-cookies/5751243#5751243

Comment: no im not :( i wrote it myself, but checked in with stack every once in a while to check if im dong it correctly. Im really new to php

Comment: sorry if its against the rules, i just needed help.

Comment: @user719813 Understood. Sorry if my comment came off rude but these types of questions are typically easy to debug even for a beginner. Keep asking/learning though! :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to echo.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE["uuid"]))
   setcookie("uuid", "$rnd_id", time()+368400000);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

youre echoing the cookie!

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE["uuid"])) {
   setcookie("uuid", "$rnd_id", time()+368400000);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't echo it? if you only want to set it:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE["uuid"]))
   setcookie("uuid", "$rnd_id", time()+368400000);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["uuid"]))
   echo $_COOKIE["uuid"] ;
else
   setcookie("uuid", $rnd_id, time()+368400000);
?>
```