# How to save uuid value for visitor

Tags: php, cookies, uuid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set cookies for uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750658/how-to-set-cookies-for-uuid)

Hello here's my site, http://xblgenerator.co.cc . It generates a random id everytime the page is loaded. I want to make a script which saves the output if the id generator for a returning user. For example, if a user visits my site, and gets this id: http://xblgenerator.co.cc/id=12345 , i want the user to see that same id if he refreshes/reloads the page. Maybe this can be done with cookies, but i didn't have any success with it. Here's my cookie script which doesnt work,

```
setcookie('firstvisit', 1);
setcookie('uuid', $rnd_id, time()+368400);
if(isset($_COOKIE['firstvisit']) && isset($_COOKIE['uuid'])) {
    // load uuid content
}
```

Please dont answer that I should use sessions because I want the id to remain the same for the visitor for a month. I don't want to use databases either. Can somebody tell me what to change in the script above, or what else to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you check the cookie value before setting it, otherwise it will be overwritten every time and you won't know if the user's browser has already passed in an existing cookie. Other than that, this looks correct.

Comment: well the result of the id generator is has a variable of $rnd_id so believe it is correct, but for some reason it doesnt seem to save the id.

Answer (score 0):

You website doesn't seem to set the cookie right. I was there and I see two cookies 1.firstvisit  and 2.uuid . Now, uuid has the value of your script name. You want to put the value of the generated ID NOT the script name (random_id.php)

1. put in the value as the generated ID
2. as the previous answer states, don't set the cookie before checking it.

   ```
   <?php if(cookie exists)
   {
     returning user;
     do_process();
   }else {
     new user; 
     set cookie; 
     do_process();
   }
   ```

   ?>

Comment: well i changed the cookie value, `<? setcookie('uuid', $rnd_id, time()+368400);
if(isset($_COOKIE['uuid']) && isset($_COOKIE['uuid'])) {
    // load uuid content
} ?>` but it still doesnt work

Comment: I don't see the second cookie.

Comment: i changed it once again, but its still not working properly. `<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["uuid"]))
   $_COOKIE["user"] . "!<br />";
else
  ; setcookie('uuid', $rnd_id, time()+368400000);
?>` help