# How to track clicks on a php element?

Tags: php, uuid, counter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set cookies for uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750658/how-to-set-cookies-for-uuid)

Hello, I have a unique id generator ( *uniqid()* ) on my site which generates a unique id for every new visitor (the id's are saved in cookies for every user). Each visitor gets their own special link in this format: http://website.com/id=12345. Check out my site to see what i mean: (please don't say that im "phishing", "scamming", etc. This site project is actually going to be a real working system when complete.) http://freexboxlivecodes.cz.cc

My question is how to track **unique** clicks on the unique link every vistor gets using php. I tried some scripts but they all require that i paste a specific page to track. If anyone knows how this can be done, please answer. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't define what you mean by "track", or by "unique".

Comment: you can track using sessions instead,
session_start();

Comment: i cant use sessions because they are deleted when the browser is closed. I need the unique link to be preserved for a month.

Comment: @ tomalak, unique means one of a kind (doesnt count the same ip twice) I meant track as in count

Comment: I really hate those "spam your link to get <free item/porn/whatever>` sites. IMO they all deserve to disappear from the internet and never come back.

Comment: did you even read what i said -.- this isnt going to be a spamming site.

Comment: in this case you can do like statckoverflow and use cookies.

Comment: Thats's what my first thought was, but can someone show a script which could work?

Comment: Stating that it isn't going to be a spamming site doesn't mean that that's true.

Answer (score 2):

The only honest answer is: You can't. There are basically two possible approaches, but all of them flawed:

- Using a cookie: Cookies can be deleted, quite simply.
- Using the IP-address: Depending on your provider your IP will change every now and then. Furthermore a proxy server may be used.

Comment: you can, i saw a site do this (cant name it) and i know its possible

Comment: @user: Not really. It'll work for the average user, yes, but if someone wants to trick your counter, he will have no problem doing so.

Comment: In addition, the IP method is flawed in more ways. In my area all mobile traffic is under the same IP (maybe it's a couple of addresses, I have only seen one). This means that many users can be counted as one.

Comment: nikic is correct. It is impossible to detect a returning visitor with 100% certainty for the reasons he posted. Of course you can detect how often a link is clicked so long as it points to a PHP script that you control, but you don't really know for sure who clicked it :P

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie and store the IP. If the cookie exists or the IP has accessed the link recently, do not count the click.

Using something like [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie) might also be helpful against cheaters.

Comment: yeah, that's what i hope to do, but i need a sample script as an example.