# How to count and display clicks on a link

Tags: php, html, counter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set cookies for uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750658/how-to-set-cookies-for-uuid)

Hello, my question is how to count and display clicks on a php value (since the link id changes a lot, ex. http://site.com/id=232323) . so for example, i want to display this

`http://gjfkgfkgf.com/id=12345- 323 clicks`

instead of this

```
http://gjfkgfkgf.com/id=12345
```

Comment: What's the question? Oh, and BTW, that isn't a valid PHP `GET` variable.

Comment: what are you talking about? i didnt enter any get variable. The question is in the title.

Comment: `http://gjfkgfkgf.com/id=12345` isn't valid. `http://gjfkgfkgf.com/?id=12345` is. Also, you ask *questions* here, not "write meh teh codez plz" requests. I'm quite sure Google would've helped you greatly.

Comment: @Blender: Just FYI, with a little `.htaccess` fun `http://gjfkgfkgf.com/id=12345` is easily valid. So that's hardly relevant to the question. Otherwise I agree, though

Comment: You can do anything with a `.htaccess` file ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create a MySQL table with the fields `id` and `count`

Every time the site is loaded, connect to the MySQL database, fetch the `count` value from the database using the id in the URL, add 1 to the count and `UPDATE` the MySQL row with the new count.

If you feel like being advanced you can add 1 to the count column with a single query :-)

```
UPDATE linkcount
SET `count`=`count`+1
WHERE `id`='12345'
```

Now you can fetch the number of visits to a specific link by

```
SELECT `count`
FROM linkcount
WHERE `id`='12345'
```

Comment: the 'id' is text. The actual id is a uniqid()

Comment: so? `uniqid()` also outputs a string

Comment: use `count = count + 1` not the subselect.

Comment: well, i still dont use mysql so this isnt for me

Comment: You can use SQLite. It's like MySQL, but writes its database to a single file. No daemons or anything, so it's (as the name suggests), light.

Comment: user719813: If you're not using any sort of database then this task is going to get very advanced. You might also want to mention in the initial question that databases is out of the question. You might want to think about the quality of your questions in general, as quite honestly your accept ratio is terrible :-)